# How can I make the summary field required?

Tags: entities

Is there a way to make the summary field required by default in the node form?

Comment: Same answer as here 

http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/34205/is-it-possible-to-make-summary-mandatory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be easier to create a new field for the summary and just manage it that way, you will then have to remove the summary option from the body field. Otherwise I think you will have to write some code and use hook_form_alter.

Answer (score 0):

in a custom module, hook into the the form alter hook

```
MYMODULE_form_FORM_ID_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
   $form['body'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['summary']['#required'] = TRUE;
}
```

or

```
MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
   if ($form_id = 'MY_FORM_ID') {
       $form['body'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['summary']['#required'] = TRUE;
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Go to admin/structure/types/manage/your_content_type_name/fields; there, you have the option to make this field required.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: that option is make body field required, not summary.